# Edit multiple rows (Bulk Update) at same time in Material React Table in React Js

Tags: reactjs, datatable, material-ui, material-table, material-react-table

I want to know weather can we do Bulk update means multiple rows update at same time using this Material React Table library?
Suppose if we have one edit button on the top of Table and if we click on that edit button every row cells should be editable.
And if user edit those cells and user click on Save button(Early it was Edit button) button that is update on top of the table again.
Then every changed cell value should be updated with updated value. We have one api for bulk update.

I found one thing for bulk update with Material Table but not in Material React Table
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-p_hckSW4So

Also if i try to install Material Table then it is giving --Legacy-peer-deps error with React v18